# How to plot selective variables from a column from one dataframe using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm wondering how to plot bar graphs/box plots for selective variables from a single column instead of the entire set of variables within a column using ggplot in R.

e.g. only plotting df$colors == "red", "orange", "blue" and ignoring the rest

```
**colors**
red
red
blue
blue
yellow
yellow
green
orange
```

My second question is a variant of the first, where I would like to plot according to the above criterion but in addition, based on criterion on a second column's variables. So for example, having a second column:

```
**shapes**
triangle
triangle
square
circle
circle
circle
rectangle
```

and then only plotting for df$colors == "red", "blue", "orange" and df$shapes == "circle".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add an excerpt of your data? It's going to make easier to answer.

Comment: You can specify subsets of your data by the way you enter it, e.g. ````ggplot(data = df[df$colors == "red" & df$colors == "blue" & df$shapes == "circle",], aes(...))```` etc.. If you think that's too messy, maybe consider subsetting the data prior to plotting?